# Type definitions for Redux (Toolkit) store with preloadedState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, types, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to make typings work for configuring a Redux store with a preloaded state.

The [Redux Toolkit TypeScript quick start guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript) has this example:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    one: oneSlice.reducer,
    two: twoSlice.reducer
  }
})

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

Unfortunately with a preloaded state, it looks more like this:

```
export function initStore(preloadedState) {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      one: oneSlice.reducer,
      two: twoSlice.reducer
    },
    preloadedState,
  })

  return store
}
```

From where do I now get the `RootState` type and the `AppDispatch` type?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### State from Reducer

You can infer the type of your state based on the argument types of your reducers.  We will want to separate the `reducer` value into a separate `const` in order to use `typeof` on just the reducer.

```
const reducer = {
  one: oneSlice.reducer,
  two: twoSlice.reducer
};
```

You are using an object of slice reducers rather than a function created [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers).  Redux toolkit exports a utility type that we can use to infer the state from reducer map object notation.

```
import { StateFromReducersMapObject } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export type RootState = StateFromReducersMapObject<typeof reducer>
```

#### Return Types

We could have just as well gotten the type for the `Store` by looking at the `ReturnType` of `initStore` and then gotten the `RootState` by looking at the `ReturnType` from the store's `getState` method. That would be the most similar to the example.  This same approach also allows us to get the type for `AppDispatch`.  Note that we use bracket notation instead of dot notation because our `Store` is a `type`, not an `object`.

```
type Store = ReturnType<typeof initStore>
type RootState = ReturnType<Store['getState']>
type AppDispatch = Store['dispatch']
```

#### PreloadedState Type

The advantage of separating the `reducer` outside of `initStore` is that we can now use the types from the reducer to declare the appropriate type for the `preloadedState` argument, which was not typed before.

```
import { configureStore, Slice, StateFromReducersMapObject, PreloadedState } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const reducer = {
  one: oneSlice.reducer,
  two: twoSlice.reducer
};

export type RootState = StateFromReducersMapObject<typeof reducer>

export function initStore(preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) {
  return configureStore({
    reducer,
    preloadedState,
  });
}

type Store = ReturnType<typeof initStore>

export type AppDispatch = Store['dispatch']
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mxBjGw)

Comment: Just want to add ... so cool! Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @linda-paiste I tried your solution, everything is good except that the type of `preloadedState` which is `DeepPartial<RootState>` is not compatible to parameter `preloadedState`. You can see the error in the TS Playground link you provided.

Comment: @cadenzah Thanks for pointing that out!  The RTK package changed -- the correct type used to be `DeepPartial` but there is now a specific `PreloadedState` type that needs to be used instead.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I stumbled across this answer after I had already implemented something like this and I expected it to work. However, when I create my src/app/hooks.ts file such as

`import type {AppDispatch, RootState} from './store'; export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch;` and then subsequently run `const dispatch = useAppDispatch()` typescript is interpreting `useAppDispatch` as having a return type of `unknown`. 

Have you resolved this issue already?

Comment: Never mind, apparently you had to have redux installed! It was being included via a peer dependency, but because it wasn't discreetly installed it wasn't figuring it out.