# TypeScript: How to type a returned function's return type

Tags: typescript, redux, types

Still trying to learn this typing system not sure if it's possible.

I'm working with redux and the redux toolkit, and it's mentioned that after creating the redux store, you can create a typed version of the store's dispatch and state.

Directly from their site:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// ...

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    one: oneSlice.reducer,
    two: twoSlice.reducer
  }
});

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

My question is that I need to defer configuration of the store.

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// ...

const createStore = () => configureStore({
  reducer: {
    one: oneSlice.reducer,
    two: twoSlice.reducer
  }
});

// in some other class ///
const store = createStore();
```

Is there anyway to get the types mentioned from the first method to actually be used within code?

**edit**
I am looking to be able to annotate the `store` constant in the last example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is it that you want to explicitly annotate the type of `store` in the last example or that you want to annotate the return type of `createStore`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I would like to annotate the type of `store` in the last example

Comment: In the second example add `export type MyStore = ReturnType<typeof createStore>;` to the module exporting `createStore`. Then you can import the type and use. I consider this a bad practice. Type inference is your friend

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry, I mispoke about what types I needed. I would like the types of the created `store`'s `dispatch` and `getState` method. The first example creates the `store` and then infers the types from the resultant store. But I can't do that in the 2nd example because i can't export the types once the store is created from within the factory method

Comment: You can use the indexed access type syntax (`type[memberKey]`) to obtain the types of members of the result. For example: `export const createStore =...;` `export type GetState = ReturnType<typeof createStore>["getState"];` `export type Dispatch = ReturnType<typeof createStore>["dispatch"];`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Very cool, if you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I did modify it though to actually be `export type AppState = ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof createStore>['getState']>;`. Your way gave me the return type of `() => state` where I needed `state`

Comment: I answered a very similar question a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/66324900/10431574 in that question they wanted the option to pass in a initial state so it's a tiny bit different than @Aluan's answer, but mostly the same.

Comment: @LindaPaiste yes, that is indeed a solid answer to a very similar question and well worth a look by the OP

Comment: @LindaPaiste thanks I will check that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a matter of drilling down into functions return type to obtain the type of a member of the return type.

We can use TypeScript's [Indexed Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures) to accomplish this as follows

```
type MemberType = MyType[memberKey];
```

In which we obtain the type of the member with the key `memberKey` of the type `MyType`, where `memberKey` is a valid key such a string or number literal or constant or a unique symbol.

In this case, to obtain the types of members `getState` and `dispatch` of the object returned by `createStore` when it is called, we would write

```
// store.ts

export const createStore = () => configureStore({
  reducer: {
    one: oneSlice.reducer,
    two: twoSlice.reducer
  }
});

// The type of the member `dispatch` of the store returned by `createStore`.
export type StoreDispatch = ReturnType<typeof createStore>["dispatch"];

// The type of the member `getState` of the store returned by `createStore`.
export type StoreGetState = ReturnType<typeof createStore>["getState"];
```

Note that we can continue to drill down, for example to get the return types of these members as in

```
// The return type of the member `getState` of the store returned by `createStore`.
export type AppState = ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof createStore>["getState"]>;
```

As such syntax can become unwieldy, we can use intermediate type declarations to break it down into a more readable form

```
type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof createStore>;

type AppStoreGetState = AppStore["getState"];

export type AppState = ReturnType<AppStoreGetState>;
```

At any rate, we can now consume these types just like any others.

The following is a contrived example

```
// test.ts

import { createStore, AppState } from "./store";

const store = createStore();

const state: AppState = store.getState();
```